# Detect the percentage of the horizontal position that users click on

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a slider from scratch like the jQuery UI one but i'm not sure how to detect the horizontal position where the user clicks on the slider.

Example, if i click on `foo` div in the middle, it'd return 50%. If i have that it would be easy for me to adjust the slider's filler div width accordingly.

Comment: You want this with or without jQuery?

Comment: @Niels I don't mind if it's with jQuery.

Comment: The click event object has .offsetX and .offsetY, which is the x/y location of a click relative the target object's top left corner. Once you know how wide/tall that particular object is, it's easy to figure out the percentages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UCFtB/1/

Script:

```
$("#test").mousemove(function(e){
    var perc = e.offsetX/ $(this).width() * 100;
    $(this).html(e.offsetX + " | " + perc + " perc");
});
```